# The package javax.bluetooth is not accessible in Eclipse

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I'm a new Eclipse user and have just installed the software and along with the `bluecove-2.1.1 jar`.

I did follow the instruction to import the jar file into my workspace.
However, when I import the `javax.bluetooth.*` in my project, there's an error "The package javax.bluetooth is not accessible". I did try several ways to fix this and none of them have worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with bluecove and java and I had the same problem.

Install bluecove-2.1.1 SNAPSHOT instead of bluecove-2.1.1 or any other version.

This worked in my case.

[bluecove-2.1.1 SNAPSHOT](https://project.fit.cvut.cz/trac/SmartBuildings/export/916/trunk/install/BlueTooth/bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar)